# How do we separate clusters with colors without using "kmeans.labels_.astype(float)"?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, scatter-plot, data-mining

I'm having problems with separating clusters using colors. I did a k-means clustering with 3 clusters for the sample data (n=30), but somehow the plot only shows 2 clusters, with a centroid placed in the middle of the missing 3rd cluster.
Here's the [Scatter Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCYgR.png) i made, and the [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0ZLn.png) for it.

'''python

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import seaborn as sns

# Definition
Data = {'x':[25,34,22,27,33,33,31,22,35,34,67,54,57,43,50,57,59,52,65,47,49,48,35,33,44,45,38,43,51,46],
    'y':[79,51,53,78,59,74,73,57,69,75,51,32,40,47,53,36,35,58,59,50,25,20,14,12,20,5,29,27,8,7]}
df = DataFrame(Data,columns=['x','y'])
X = df[['x','y']].copy()

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3,init='k-means++',max_iter=100,n_init=30,random_state=0).fit(df)
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
print(centroids)
```

`# Plotting the graph and centroids`

```
plt.scatter(df['x'],df['y'],c=kmeans.labels_.astype(float),s=100,alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(centroids[:,0],centroids[:,1],c='red',s=100)
```

'''

I identified the problem which was the coloring line:

```
c=kmeans.labels_.astype(float)
```

As a reference, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYP2G.png) is another scatter plot without the labels line, only using "c='black'".

As far as i've searched the forums, it seems like using the line is common for separating the clusters, yet i still have no clue on where the problem may be. If you have a reference stating the solution to a similar problem, please share it here.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: The problem is an acute case of color blindness :) Your 'missing' cluster is colored in a light yellow, which is hard to spot.

Comment: wow at a second viewing, you're right and i feel dumb for it :'D is there anyway that i can change the light yellow to something darker?

Comment: Well, one way would be, to cluster your data using the labels. I am not at a computer right now, but out of my head you do something like: for u in np.unique(labels): cluster[u] = data[labels=u]. Then you plot and color each cluster individually.